# How do I only receive new links from a page monitor created in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've written a page monitor to receive the latest product link from Nike.com, but I only want it to return a link to me if it's from a product that has just been uploaded to the site. I haven't been able to find any help similar to this. This is the page monitor written in Python. Any help with Python returning only new links would be helpful.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import json

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36'
}


def item_finder():

    source = requests.get('https://www.nike.com/launch/', headers=headers).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

    card = soup.find('figure', class_='item ncss-col-sm-12 ncss-col-md-6 ncss-col-lg-4 va-sm-t pb2-sm pb4-md prl0-sm prl2-md ')

    card_data = "https://nike.com" + card.a.get('href')

    print(card_data)

item_finder()
```